# Some text not displaying after heroku deployment

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, frontend

so I recently deployed my web application on heroku.. And for some weird reason, some of my text is not showing up (You can see the difference between both screenshots below)

The one with the missing font is deployed.

So I checked everywhere and i couldn't find anything, also the font is correctly loading since the other text that is correctly showing up is using the same font "Open Sans". Here is the screenshots 
[image]

Deployed app: https://oh-my-game-portal.herokuapp.com/

Comment: How are you using the font in your app ? you provided only one screenshot link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a opacity property of 1% on the text you're missing. The css for the label seems to have a value of 75% though.

[image: From Inspector]

Comment: Yup, well for some reason i just removed the opacity property from the css and the text is now showing up. I feel really stupid now lol.. Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: Happens to everybody ;) I'm also not sure where the 1% came from, but I wouldn't use opacity at the label anyways. If you want it to look less heavy, change the color to a grey or use opacity as color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) (or hsla) :)

Comment: Thanks dude.Wasted 2 hours trying to fix.Thanks!!!!